# Check if user inputs value within X time using C++

Tags: c++, input, timer

I'm making a game and I want to have a timer that runs in the background.  If the user does not enter anything within the provided time limit then they lose.

I already have the timer and separate threads working properly, however, I am unsure as to how I can have the program check if the user provided a value for the input.  If the user did not enter anything then the timer should continue to countdown until the time runs out, at which point the program exits.

I envision the pseudo-code something like this:

```
do
{
    CheckIfUserInputs;

    //skip this if there is no input
    if(UserInput == WinningPhrase)
    {
        cout<< "You win\n";
        PlayerWon = true;
    }
}while((time > 0) && (PlayerWon != true));
```

Comment: You haven't specified a lot: 1) Platform?, 2) Console or GUI?, 3) What libraries are you using? Please be more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `cin.eof()`.  Should return -1 if there isn't anything.